# How do I process an input file with int's and string's

Tags: java, string, file, arraylist, int

For part of my weekly labs/homework I've been asked to process a text file and push it to a database using jdbc. First of all I'm trying to figure out how to split up the individual contents of the file which is structured as follows:

1   Alain A   2   75
2   Michael B   3   85
3   Chen C   1   55
4   Caroline D   2   60
5   Mohamed E   2   60
6   Alex F   1   55
7   Sofia O   3   78
8   Samir O   1   85
9   Rob G   2   78
10   Big K   3   55

The first number is the student id, string is the student name with surname initial, the last two ints are the students year and their mark.

I think once I have divided this input into separate arraylists I can figure out how to push it to the database fairly easily but the trouble I'm having is splitting up the input. I had tried populating 4 separate arraylists by using an incremental counter that chooses which arraylist to push to and resets back to 1 when it goes over 4.

e.g (not proper code):

```
while (scanner.hasNext()){ 
  if(counter > 4){counter = 1;}
  if (counter == 1){arraylist1.add;}     
  if (counter == 2){arraylist2.add;}   
  if (counter == 3){arraylist3.add;}   
  if (counter == 4){arraylist4.add;}   
  counter++;  
}
```

This doesn't work which to be honest I fully expected but I don't know how to go about solving this problem. I still want to populate 4 different arraylists so I have the information divided and can still refer to a whole set just by using the same index across the lists.

Comment: Look at the Scanner class. It has methods like `nextInt` that you'll find useful.

Comment: I suggest you use an Object for each row to represent all the fields in that row.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong. You do not use several lists to hold that data.

You create **one** class that represents a row, lets call it the `StudentMark` class. And that class contains fields for ID, Name, grade, ...

You read the file line by line; and for each line you push the strings into the StudentMark constructor (for example). To be precise: you want to decouple things even more; like having a `Parser` class that takes a single line from the file input. The parser then splits the input into the fields; and well, *parses* the expected content (for example using Integer.parseInt() to turn grade strings into real numbers). Then that data is used to create new `StudentMark` objects; and  are then added to a single `List<StudentMark>`.

One core thing about good OO: you try to create helpful data structures that *model* the aspects of reality you are dealing with. Using flat lists to keep such "table" data is of course possible; but hey: you choose an object oriented, statically typed programming language. So, to make use of the *advantages* of that context, you want to **avoid** using flat lists of lists of strings.